# Object property is NULL, in MVC Edit action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Using below models

```
public class State
{
    public int StateId { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int CityId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public State state { get; set; }
}
```

and following View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>City</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CityId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.state.StateId)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.state.Name)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.state.Code)


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

I see the `State` is `NULL` in my controller

```
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "CityId,Name")] City city)
{
    // City.State is NULL and ModelSAtate.IsValid is FALSE
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(city).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(city);
}
```

By this mean, `City.State` is `NULL`.

I know the workaround to make `ModelState.IsValid` to `TRUE` but I like to know the right way for hanlding object property in MVC View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should to add also these hidden property if you want to catch `State` entity  in your action as a part of `City`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.state.StateId)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.state.Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.state.Code)
```

EDIT: 
I also had to remove the `Bind()` section so my action look like

```
public ActionResult Edit(City city)
```

Comment: It's still null

Comment: Where is declaration of form in your view?

Comment: I added complete view in the question

Comment: Do I need to add anything in Bind() ?

Comment: If I want to keep Bind() there, do I need to list all fields?

Comment: Glad to have been of help. I think there is no reason to use Bind.  Of course you can try something like :`Edit([Bind(Include = "CityId,Name")] City city, Bind(Include = "StateId,Name,Code")] State state)`. But I'm not sure that it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you try to process a request from your view to your controller, MVC Routing tries to identify which controller action to invoke according to your route configuration. This job is assigned to the ControllerActionInvoker. After successfully identifying which action to invoke, now the default model binder takes control of binding the model correctly.

The Default Model Binding(DefaultModelBinder) works in the following order :-

1. Request.Form - Values submitted in the form
2. RouteData.Values - Route values e.g. id in /Employee/Edit/{id}
3. Request.QueryString - Data extracted from the query string portion of the URL
4. Request.Files - Uploaded Files

   There are ways to customize your binding behaviour, you may find this article interesting - https://mono.software/2017/02/09/model-binding-asp-net-mvc/

But for your problem, the given answer by @Marusyk is sufficient enough. Happy coding...